# Beamer Dresden Theme remove subsections

Tags: beamer

I'd like to remove the bar under the navigation bar, that shows the subsection (see picture). I use the Dresden Theme and seagull color theme: http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/individual/Dresden-seagull-default.html

Is there a nice way to do this?

```
\usetheme[compress]{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied the `headline` template from the `miniframes` outer theme (the one used in `Dresden`) and remove the part displaying the subsection.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{seagull}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{miniframes theme no subsection}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[miniframes theme no subsection]

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Something}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
\subsection{Something else}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Bad News: Hardness Results}
\subsection{Something}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
\subsection{Something else}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}

\section{Good News: Tractability Resulsts}
\subsection{Something}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
\subsection{Something else}
\frame{}

\section{Summary}

\end{document}
```

> [image]